# How can I convert function types with the same signature?

Tags: go

In a package, I have this:

```
package pkg1

type SomeFuncType func (a interface{}, b interface{}) int

func PkgApiCall (x SomeFuncType) {
   ...
}
```

In my code using this package, I have some very similar:

```
type MyFuncType func (a interface{}, b interface{}) int
```

Now I want to call `pkg1.PkgApiCall()`, but with a variable of `MyFuncType` as argument:

```
package mypackage

func doingSomeThing(x MyFuncType) {
  pkg1.PkgApiCall(x)
}
```

It doesn't compile. I get the error

```
./src1.go:97:7: error: incompatible type in initialization (cannot use type mypackage.MyFuncType as type pkg1.SomeFuncType)
```

How could I get over this? These function types define functions with exactly the same signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual type conversions work for function types just as well as they work for non-function types:

```
pkg1.PkgApiCall(SomeFuncType(x))
```