# confusing syntax of array of first class functions in golang

Tags: go

I'm new to `Go`. Confused about the following code:

```
  0  package main                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  1
  2 import "fmt"
  3
  4 type job func(in, out chan interface{})
  5
  6 func main() {
  7     myJobs := []job{
  8         job(func(in, out chan interface{}) {
  9             fmt.Println("marker 1")
 10         }),
 11         job(func(in, out chan interface{}) {
 12             fmt.Println("marker 1")
 13         }),
 14     }
 15 }
```

I understand that line 4 defines a new type job. However I'm confused in how it is used on lines 8 and 11. Usually I would define a type like this when I return it from another function. This particular usage is new to me and I don't understand it. On lines 8 and 11. Specifically I don't understand what those lines do. From the context I figured that it is a slice of jobs, but I just don't get the syntax. `job` is a type, so it looks like what is happening is `<type>(func(in, out chan interface{})`. I feel like I'm missing something important and obvious. I would appreciate any help with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert function types with the same signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899868/how-can-i-convert-function-types-with-the-same-signature)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) may be confusing things; this is not actually needed in this case and the following will also work (and is a bit easier to understand):

```
myJobs2 := []job{
        func(in, out chan interface{}) {
            fmt.Println("marker 1")
        },
        func(in, out chan interface{}) {
            fmt.Println("marker 1")
        },
    }
```

I have saved an example in the [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/T3fA0h_nZ3A).